# R - Is the result of tapply always in alphabetical order

Tags: r, tapply

I work with the dataframe df

```
Name = c("Albert", "Caeser", "Albert", "Frank")
Earnings = c(1000,2000,1000,5000)
df = data.frame(Name, Earnings)


Name        Earnings

Albert      1000
Caesar      2000
Albert      1000
Frank       5000
```

If I use the tapply function

```
result <- tapply(df$Earnings, df$Name, sum)
```

I get this table *result*

```
Albert  2000
Caeser  2000
Frank   5000
```

Are there any circumstances, under which the table "result" would not be ordered alphabetically, if I use the tapply function as described above?

When I tried to find an answer, I changed the order of the rows:

```
Name        Earnings
Frank       5000
Caeser      2000
Albert      1000
Albert      1000
```

but still get the same result.

I use multiple functions where I calculate with the output of tapply calculations and I have to be absolutely sure, that the output is always delivered in the same order.

Comment: I would just use `data.table` as in `library(data.table) ; setDT(df)[, sum(Earnings), Name]` and solve this specific problem and many other

Comment: The results are in the order of the levels of the index. The default order of "unordered" factors is alphabetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the output is ordered, but you can come up with examples where it is not. For example if you have factors with unordered levels.

```
df <- data.frame(Name = factor(c('Ben', 'Al'), levels = c('Ben', 'Al')),  
                 Earnings = c(1, 4))
tapply(df$Earnings, df$Name, sum)
## Ben  Al 
##   1   4
```

In that case you can either use `as.character` or (probably saver) order the result afterwards.

```
tapply(df$Earnings, as.character(df$Name), sum)
##  Al Ben 
##   4   1 

result <- tapply(df$Earnings, df$Name, sum)
result[order(names(result))]
##  Al Ben 
##   4   1
```

Another possible problem can be leading spaces:

```
df <- data.frame(Name = c(' Ben', 'Al'),  
                 Earnings = c(1, 4))
tapply(df$Earnings, df$Name, sum)
##  Ben   Al 
##    1    4
```

In that case, just remove all leading spaces to get results ordered.

Comment: In the leading spaces examply, `tapply` is sorting the output, a space is just prioritized after 'z'. I.e.,  `sort(c(" ben", " al"))` returns `[1] " al"  " ben"`. The only problem would be the inconsistent use of leading spaces. edit: I as wrong about ordering, spaces come first. See Shadow's below comment.

Comment: @bjoseph Actually, it seems that spaces come before the 'A': `sort(c('A', ' '))`. But yes, the problem is still inconsistent leading spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can order `sapply` output as you order any array in R. Using the [[sort]](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sort.html) command.[1](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sort.html)

```
> result
Albert Caeser  Frank 
  2000   2000   5000 

> sort(result,decreasing=TRUE)
 Frank Albert Caeser 
  5000   2000   2000
```

Depending on what you want to order by, you can either sort the values as shown above (by leaving `decreasing` NULL, i.e. `sort(result)` you will get values in increasing order), or by sorting the names:

This will deliver the results by `name` in reverse alphabetical order
    `result[sort(names(result),decreasing=TRUE)]`

```
 Frank Caeser Albert 
  5000   2000   2000
```

What else would you like to sort and order by?

Comment: thx for your anwer. My questions is rather about "the function behind the function" (tapply): Are there any circumstances, under which tapply results would not be ordered alphabetically, if I use the tapply function on a column with characters, as described above?