# improvement on tapply (shifting groups of vectors)

Tags: r, group-by, tapply, split-apply-combine

[The order of the return object from `tapply()` is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28412707/r-is-the-result-of-tapply-always-in-alphabetical-order), so I've started to worry about this bit of code:

```
#d <- data.frame(value = c(1,2,3,5), 
#               source = c("a","a","b","b"))
d$value <- unlist(tapply(d$value, d$source, function(v) v-v[1]))
```

The idea is to split `value` into groups, then and then shift each group of its element so that the group starts off at 0.

**What's a better way to do this?** I have several ideas, but I can't think of anything that

- doesn't make use of third-party libraries
- is still a one-liner
- avoids an R loop
- does not involve sorting/merging the original data frame.

Comment: Is `d` assumed to be sorted by `source`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little-known trick in base R is the `split(x, y) <- lapply(split(x, y), f)` paradigm, so the following one-liner meets all your requirements:

```r
d <- data.frame(value = c(1,2,3,5), 
                source = c("a","a","b","b"))

split(d$value, d$source) <- lapply(split(d$value, d$source), \(x) x - x[1])
```

Resulting in:

```r
d
#>   value source
#> 1     0      a
#> 2     1      a
#> 3     0      b
#> 4     2      b
```

Whatever the ordering of `source`

<sup>Created on 2023-06-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Hope `ave` makes sense

```
> transform(d,value = ave(value,source, FUN = \(x) x-x[1]))
  value source
1     0      a
2     1      a
3     0      b
4     2      b
```